# Using table row and column header information in IBM Watson Discovery service

Tags: ibm-watson, watson-discovery

My team wants to apply cognitive search to a large body of unstructured "Policy" documents (for example, Automobile Insurance Policy documents). Some of the information in these documents is organized within formatted tables. A human reader would use row and column headings to interpret the documents.

For example, my policy coverage may differ depending on the nature of an incident and which of my vehicles is involved. In the context of my solution, this information is available in a table within on of thepolicy documents, where the rows of the table lists the various types of incidents, and columns list the different vehicles covered in the policy. Each table cell describes the coverage for a specific incident / vehicle combination.

The natural thing to do, would be to annotate each table cell with relationships to the column and row headers for that cell. I'm hoping Watson Discovery already does this or can do this for me. However, in my experiments, I'm not seeing results that would indicate this is so. Are there facililies in either Discovery or Watson Knowledge Studio that facilitate taking advantage of the information in Row and Column headers, within tables?

Answer (score 0):

Table contents are structured data and not suitable for WKS/Discovery for analyzing.
WKS accept plain text of natural language text. Although Discovery accepts HTML/WORD/PDF document, the ingested document is converted into plain text in pre-process and all table structures will be removed. Therefore relations of table are not considered in the text analyzing.
I recommend you to handle such table contents data as a structured data and handle them in other method like programmatically.